# Can modifiers such as "Subdivision" and "Array" be "animated"?

Tags: modifiers, animation

Suppose I wanted to animate an object growing out of the ground, or turning from a cube to a much smoother shape, could I animate this using modifiers and key frames?

I know I can use shape keys to achieve something similar, but modifiers would make it easier and smoother. Is this possible?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Jonathan's answer is correct. However, your original question states:

> I know I can use shape keys to achieve something similar, but modifiers would make it **easier and smoother.**

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

In fact, properties that can only have integer values (i.e., no decimals) can only be animated with constant interpolation:

[image: Constant interpolation in the graph editor]

This is, by any definition, the exact opposite of smooth.

If you really want it to be smooth, **consider using a shape key!**

1. Subdivide your mesh however many times you want in Edit Mode.
2. Add a shape key.
3. Press **Smooth Vertex** in the toolbox and adjust the iteration count (10 works well for two levels of subdivision).
4. Animate the shape key.

This will get you a nice Beziér (or linear, if you prefer) interpolation:

[image: Beziér interpolation in the graph editor]

I've prepared [a video](https://vimeo.com/68009707) to demonstrate the difference. The first part of the video uses the shape key method, while the second part uses a modifier with the "Levels" property animated.

Comment: Thanks for setting me straight there. I realize I was wrong about that one.

Answer (score 22):

You sure can! You can animate any of the values in the modifiers by **Right Clicking** on the field and choosing *Insert Keyframe*. Then insert another frame further down the timeline where you wish.

[image: Inserting a keyframe on a modifier value]

You can also insert keyframes from a value by hovering your mouse on it and pressing <kbd>I</kbd>, or you can remove keyframes on the current frame by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>.

Answer (score 11):

Drivers can also be used to interactively animate Modifiers.

You right click on the Subdivision parameter that needs to be driven, add a driver and then in the Graph Editors 'Drivers' view, set up the drivers.

As you can see below, the z translation of two different empty objects is used to drive the modifier subsurf levels of two mesh objects. Only the viewport display levels are being driven. The Z location is stored in a driver variable and ten its absolute value is passed to a ceiling function so that only positive integers are generated. The ceil and abs functions are part of the math module that is automatically imported into the driver namespace.

[image: Two Empty objects driving the subdivision levels on two different mesh objects]

You can also access scene data like the current frame number like so for creating driver expressions

context.scene.frame_current

Reference: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/drivers/index.html#drivers

Comment: By the way, in drivers, you can just use `frame` for the frame number.