# How can I animate my Cycles shaders?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, animation

For a scene, I have to change shader parameters (using nodes in Cycles) as time goes on in the scene.

I've looked for a node that inputs a time sweep or frame number, but neither is available in Cycles. Am I looking in the wrong place? Or is there a workaround/trick I don't know about?

Comment: You can also see http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/164/can-modifiers-such-as-subdivision-and-array-be-animated/170#170

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can keyframe any value on the nodes by **Right Clicking** on the value and then choosing *Insert Keyframe*. This will set a keyframe on the current frame.

When you add a keyframe the field will turn yellow to indicate there's a keyframe on that frame. If you move along the timeline, the field will turn green to indicate the field is keyframed, but not on the current frame.

[image: Inserting a keyframe on a node value]

Answer (score 12):

If you want to do this often and want to be even faster, you can also always just press <kbd>`I`</kbd> (as in "Insert Keyframe") while your mouse is over basically any value field/button/dropdown/selector/... in Blender and it will insert a keyframe for your current frame.

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>`I`</kbd> to remove it again.

Comment: Is this the capital letter i or the lowercase letter L?

Comment: That would be the capital letter India, as in "Insert Keyframe".

_EDIT: Corrected above._