# How can I animate object properties in Blender?

Tags: animation

I was wondering if there was a method to alter object settings at a set point in an animation in blender.

For example, I want to make the color of an object blue for the first 20 frames, but after 20 frames I want its color to change to green. Is there any known method of doing this? I could not find anything when I searched.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I animate my Cycles shaders?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/176/how-can-i-animate-my-cycles-shaders/) and [Can modifiers such as “Subdivision” and “Array” be “animated”?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/164/can-modifiers-such-as-subdivision-and-array-be-animated). Welcome to Blender.SE, please search around *thoroughly* before asking.

Comment: Sorry, I did not know what keywords to search, and so I could not find it. Next time I will search harder.

Comment: Ok, np. also while an answer that is posted may be correct or suit your current need(s). Feel free to wait a while so your question can possibly attract more views and probably better or more indepth answers.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you right click on a property and click *Insert Keyframe*, you can animate that property like you would the location, rotation, scale, etc.

[image: Insert Keyframe menu]

This method works with almost all the properties including all values and most checkboxes.

**EDIT:** [Gwenn](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1284/how-can-i-animate-object-properties-in-blender#comment2190_1285) commented and noted that you can also insert the keyframe by using the <kbd>I</kbd> key. Also, you can *Remove* keyframes with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>

Comment: And where that is not possible, with the "I" hotkey

Comment: Can't animate layers anymore, though.

Comment: @hjaarnio whoa, when did that happen? Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @CharlesL http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1067/how-to-animate-layers-in-blender-2-6