# How to activate a node only on certain frames?

Tags: node-editor, video

My video clip is 60 frames long and I want a node to be active only on the last 50 frames.
How can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I animate object properties in Blender?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1284/how-can-i-animate-object-properties-in-blender)

Answer (score 1):

Just found this:
One needs to use the Right click/keyframe property on a node and set a serie of keyframes, to activate, deactivate, modulate the property.