# How to make one object gradually disappear as it passes through another object

Tags: animation, objects

How to make one object gradually disappear as it passes through some object (e.g. teleportation gates)? How to make it gradually appear in other gates?

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3589/599

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For a basic effect, you could animate the transparency.

Almost all UI properties are animatable, You can keyframe them by right clicking and selecting *Insert Keyframe* (<kbd>1</kbd> or <kbd>I</kbd>), or hovering over the value pressing <kbd>I</kbd>.

Also see

- [How can I animate my Cycles shaders?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/176/how-can-i-animate-my-cycles-shaders)
- [Can modifiers such as "Subdivision" and "Array" be "animated"?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/164/can-modifiers-such-as-subdivision-and-array-be-animated)

You could keyframe the transparency out as your object enters one gate, then keyframe the object location to move it to the other gate (or use a duplicate object) and keyframe the transparency back.

## Cycles:

You can do this in Cycles by using a mix node and animating the factor:

[image]

## Blender Internal:

This can be done in BI by enabling *Transparency* in *Properties > Materials* and animating the *Alpha*:

[image]

## Other methods:

Another way you could try is using a [*Boolean* modifier](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modifiers/Generate/Booleans) to remove parts of the object as it intersects it. You could then have a duplicate of the object moving out of another boolean cube to make it appear the sections are teleporting:

[image]

Comment: this will make whole object to appear/disapper, right? but teleportation assumes that part of the object which is not yet teleported is fully visible, other is fully invisible

Comment: @retif I'm not sure what you mean. Do you want the objects to disappear in sections? Could you add some example images?

Comment: boolean modifier method is great, exactly what i wanted, thanks! -)