# Cross section in cycles in blender 2.7

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I'd like to take a simple cross section in Blender 2.7 using the Cycles renderer. I would think this would be easy, and there is even a [tutorial about how to do it](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.4/Tutorials/Modeling/Meshes/Sectioning_a_mesh_with_nodes), but that tutorial is for Blender 2.4, and does not work with 2.7. Can someone post a simple tutorial about how to create a cross section in the latest version of blender. Here is that I have come up with so far, but the edge is not sharp and I cannot figure out how to adjust it:

[image]

Comment: Also related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/5113/599

Comment: You could get the effect you want with your existing node setup if you add a *Math node* set to *Greater than* between the gradient texture node and the mix factor. For more control, you could instead use a *color ramp node* set to *constant* interpolation in the same place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I would be trying to achieve a cross section like effect, I wouldn't use the compositor but a mesh with a boolean modifier. In my opinion it's much more flexible.

To accomplish this add a cube to our scene and position it to intersect with your object in the place you want gone. Then add a boolean modifier to  the object, select diffrence for the mode, and chose your masking cube. Be sure to disable renderability/hide the cube you masked the object with.

I have created an example in which the object being cross-sectioned is suzane in a box. You can download it [here](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/29096). Here's the example render and viewport screenshot.

[image: render]

[image: viewport]

While this method works with almost any render system, the blender internal and cycles have trouble with multimaterial objects. In that case just split it into separate objects with one material each.