# Boolean object won't disappear in render

Tags: rendering, modifiers, objects, blender-internal-render-engine

This boolean object appears when I render. I turned off the render and view option in the outliner but it still appears.

Please help! Thanks!

[image]

I tried turning off all the render and visible keyframing in the outliner, but I still get the same problem. Here is the before and after, 1st is render view and 2nd is the actual render result.

[image]

[image]

The boolean object that keeps appearing is used to hide the paper halfs, so there are no shredded papers revealed before the shredding machine, and no unshredded paper revealed after the shredding machine. Here is the result before I render below.

[image]

I get this "mask" result when I render it out, but in some parts of the animation that cube will show up. I checked my keyframe timeline and there are not keyframes near where the mask will randomly appear.

This is what i'm trying to achieve! But the boolean object keeps appearing in my render.
[image]

Comment: Have you Applied the Modifier?

Comment: Hey thanks for replying! I'm animating the position of the object that has the boolean on it, so I don't want to apply the modifier. I want the object to be revealed as it moves out of the way of the modifier.

Comment: @ Thad - I dont have time to test it out but I know the object won't be deleted if you apply the Boolean Modifier. It will still be there allowing you to animate. You may want to Apply Scale to both objects before applying the Modifier.

Comment: Selected object on the screenshot has Boolean modifier added and has its Render option in the Outliner enabled and keyframed which means it might change in the animation. Check if there is anywhere keyframe for the object to be renderable.

Comment: Hmm I turned off removed those keyframes, but I still get the same results. I'm trying to look at if I can use a mask in layers instead of boolean right now.

Comment: If object's renderability is turned off it won't be rendered. Either you see another object in the render or renderability is still enabled. Animating visiblity of the object should be possible this way as well. Eg https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5113/how-to-make-one-object-gradually-disappear-as-it-passes-through-another-object

Comment: You can move the object on a layer that won't be rendered in scene settings, but i agree with Mr Zak : turning off renderability should be enough. It's probably another object.

Comment: @ Mr Zak & @ Bithur Where would I be able to turn off the renderability? I'm a bit confused would a screenshot be possible?

Comment: I'm confused about your animation goal. Maybe you draw a few sketches (Storyboard)?

Comment: @Dontwalk I added some more images and explanations in the post above, hope it clears things up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found what was wrong.

I was using the "mask" object for 2 different boolean modifiers. I created a separate object for each boolean modifier and it rendered correctly.

Thanks for all your help!