# Animated glowing textures - how?

Tags: python, animation, materials

A common effect I'd like to understand is how to achieve moving, glowing lines. An example is on Robert Hodgin's ["Taxi, Taxi!"](http://roberthodgin.com/project/taxi-taxi). (I don't know what he uses, but have an idea it might be Houdini). Another is Cristóbal Vila's beautiful animations (e.g. [Nature by Numbers](https://youtu.be/kkGeOWYOFoA) - Mobo).

I have coded a Python script that lays out geocoded spline curves on DEM terrain together with Open Street Map building data (see [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3mtozyus4kaapyy/edinburgh_2.png?dl=0)), but the material for the moving assets is stumping me. I'd like to replicate Robert Hodgin's animation - can anyone explain in outline how this effect might be achieved in Blender?

Many thanks.

Comment: Hi. From the tag, you're specifically looking to do this with Python?

Comment: Hello Ray - the location will be dynamic and taken from a database of realtime bus movements so I imagine it will have to be coded.

Answer (score 1):

You can use curves, give them some extrusion and an emissive material. Then animate the bevel start and end factors, like in these links:

[How to create light streaks](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/34383/92768)

[How to make an object appear/visible along a path](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/149910/92768)

The main problem you will face is that you need to separate the curves created by OpenStreetMap or create new ones. OSM creates multiple segments on a single curve object and that would not work for animating Bevels.

Comment: That's helpful, thanks - I can see how that works. I've created the curves so all I have to do is create new ones for each of the moving objects. Best wishes