# How can I flatten a cube on the Z axis and make the sides protrude outwards?

Tags: animation

I am wondering how to make a cube squish like a sphere on the Z axis. It will be an animated cube, so it needs to squish like a real sphere.

Comment: Are you asking specifically about how to do it in Blender, or about animation in general?

Comment: How does a sphere squish?

Comment: I am asking how to make it squish like a sphere in blender. If you went into blender, brought out a cube and squished it down on the Z axis, you will see that the results are different than a sphere. My question is how can I make it squish like a sphere in blender.

Comment: If you go into the scale manipulatior and scale a sphere down on the z axis it will squish like a bouncy ball would squish. That is the effect I am trying to acheive.

Comment: @JoshuaSlink something like this? http://i.imgur.com/u1enUND.gif

Comment: Yes! Thank you! Could you show me how to do that?

Answer (score 3):

You can quickly achieve this with a [*Simple Deform*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modifiers/Deform/Simple_Deform) modifier set to *Stretch* and using a negative *Deform* factor.

[image]

Comment: A more efficient way could be to make a simple one bone rig and use some shapekeys but this works.

Comment: Thank you. I just have a few questions about it. If you could just give me the steps that would be great.

Comment: @JoshuaSlink The steps are in the answer ;). Just add a cube, subdivide it a couple times, add the modifier to the cube, set it to Stretch as seen in the image and use a negative deform factor, you can then keyframe this and adjust the influence etc.

Comment: When I use the negative deform factor, it does not look like yours at all. Do you know why?

Comment: @JoshuaSlink You need to subdivide the cube so it has geometry to deform. Here is a study [blend file](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/25550).

Comment: Thanks very helpful. But how did you animate with the modifier?

Comment: @JoshuaSlink See [Can modifiers such as “Subdivision” and “Array” be “animated”?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/170/12).

Comment: Could you give me the steps on how to animate it?