# Warp time with rigid body physics?

Tags: animation, physics, rigid-body-simulation

Is it possible to warp time (slow time down, speed time up) with rigid body physics?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes**, this is possible.

## 3D view physics:

Animate the *Speed* value in *Properties > Scene > Rigid body world*:

[image]

You can add [keyframes](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Animation/Basics/Actions) for this value by right clicking and selecting *Insert Keyframe*, or by pressing <kbd>I</kbd> while hovering over the field. See [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/164/599) for more detail.

## Game engine physics:

Change the *FPS* value in *Properties > World > Physics*:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this seems to have worked. Never even thought about going there...

Comment: Note that you may encounter some issues while doing this, see [here](https://developer.blender.org/T38391).