# How do i get the ocean modifier to animate?

Tags: animation, modifiers, ocean-simulation

I have been going through many tutorials and even asked in BlenderArtists but no help. When I get to the point to insert keyframes a keyframe drop down menu appears instead. It has been very frustrating to figure it out

Comment: Possible dupe? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/164/can-modifiers-such-as-subdivision-and-array-be-animated

Answer (score 7):

Insert keyframes for the "Time". Set the frame to 1, move your mouse on "Time" and press <kbd>I</kbd>
[image]
Change the frame, add some time and press <kbd>I</kbd> again.

Comment: For OP, also worth noting you can animate other properties, play around with them.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a short video tutorial on how to animate using expressions in Blender 2.80: https://youtu.be/2oUK0n5prRY

Right click on `Time`

Select `Add Driver`

Make sure you remove the `Input Variable`

Then type in this expression and you are good to go:

```
frame * 0.1 / 10
```

Answer (score 0):

I found adding a driver and changing the expression in graph editor (not sure why no one thought to allow expression editing directly in the field?!), with a reference to the current frame got it moving when playing fine.

```
(bpy.data.scenes[0].frame_current / 10)
```

The warning TIP is not important here and I just delete the variable below.

You'll have to open a node panel with the 'n' key in the graph etc. in the end it's easier just to keyframe the value, if we can't put expressions directly into the value via backticks ` like Houdini etc.
You should be able to do something directly in the field like @curframe or call a global function frame()?... alas it's free software.

Comment: Interesting. Not the easy way but no doubt it's powerful. You should explain with more details how to connect this to the ocean modifier, what can be done and how, inside blender of course.

Comment: too long? see below... or above? it's hoping around.

Answer (score 0):

Sure if you right click on any field there is "Add Driver" CTRL-D Choose Single Manually Later.

In a Graph Editor you change to view Drivers from F-Curve drop down.

Select and use 'n' to view Drivers TAB on right panel. The Scripted Expression Type has the Expr: field below that so you can then put in the Expression.

A better option is to use the C.scene where C is bpy.context but it's not set there, so `(bpy.context.scene.frame_current / 10)` would drive the ocean.

You can delete the var and don't worry about the warning like I said before.
Seems it also says it's unsafe for RenderFarm so the previous scenes[0] might be better it's all new to me so I find it lacks professionalism and clarity.

Again one should be able to just put that expression into any field directly via back-ticks or what-have-you and skip all this super confusing poorly designed hidden driver linking to graph editor expression crap.

Better yet have the ocean include a checkbox (or time link button) by default to drive it with an appropriate setting or adjustable speed slider by default [expected behavior].